# Mobile websites and Phonegap

Tags: cordova, mobile, mobile-website

I am developing a mobile application with phonegap. I want to know if I can use the phonegap code to make a mobile website, (with the same functionality) or if I have to modify it.

Can I acces the GPS and Camera through the phones browser? (Android and iOS mainly)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the GPS in mobile webkit browsers already, but not the camera.

PhoneGap APIs try to follow the W3C defined APIs, and the API documentation mentions when the native implementation is used (as is the case for geolocation [1]).  You have to check each API.

[1] http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is some early support for the MediaCapture HTML input element in several browsers, including Android and Chrome on Android. Be aware that this is a distinct thing from the full MediaCapture API, which is not supported.

The HTML MediaCapture element lets you use an input element in forms that will spawn the device's camera for still picture, audio or video capture.

You can see more details on which mobile browsers support the MediaCapture HTML API here:
http://mobilehtml5.org/

In those browsers that don't support this, there's no amount of modification to PhoneGap code that will make it work; it is just not supported.